# How to argue that two outcomes are equally likely?

Tags: probability, proof-writing

When it comes to the concept of "equally likely," students are not told what makes two outcomes equally likely, but are instead shown what it means via examples. "When flipping a coin, heads and tails are equally likely" and "When rolling a die, the faces 1-6 are equally likely" are such common examples. However, this leads me to believe that "two outcomes are equally likely" is merely an intuitive fact and cannot be justified by any logical argument.

Is it possible to justify––even better, *prove*––that two outcomes are equally likely?

For instance, how do you prove $P(heads)=P(tails)$?

The only potential justification that comes to my mind is similar to the law of large numbers: that the relative frequency of the two outcomes approaches the same number when the experiment is repeated an infinite number of times. But I see this as more of an empirical justification than an actual proof, because it is not actually possible to repeat an experiment "an infinite number of times."

Comment: If you are speaking of a physical coin, then the only "proof" would be to toss the coin a lot of times and statistically rule out significant divergence from equality.  Such an argument would never be an exact proof, of course...it would just hold up to some confidence level.  Of course, for abstract math problems we can just assume equality holds.

Comment: For the most common examples, we are working with theoretical "fair dice" and theoretical "fair coins" where we are assuming *by definition* with such objects that the outcomes are indeed equally likely.  Indeed, every problem I can think of where we utilize things that being "equally likely" is relevant it will be explicitly stated in the problem or explicitly stated in the assumptions that we are taking as an assumption that this is the case.  "*If we take a person from a population at random (where it is equally likely to have chosen any particular person)...*"

Comment: If I said "Let $f(x)=\sin(x)$", would you ask me whether I can prove that $f(x)$ actually equals $\sin(x)$?

Comment: For what its worth, in reality, we know that for most coins we can't have $\Pr(\text{heads})=\Pr(\text{tails})=0.5$ exactly since there does exist the incredibly rare but still nonzero occurrence of the coin landing on its rim and not falling to either side.

Comment: So saying two outcomes are equally likely is simply an assumption/definition? Would the sentence be considered an assumption/axiom or a definition?

Comment: I think "the probability of heads is the same as the probability of tails" is indeed a "modelling assumption". It can't be *proved*, but it can be *justified* empirically or by arguing about the mechanics of tossing a coin. There are situations where two outcomes being equally likely is not purely an assumption, but a (provable) consequence of other assumptions. EG "if you flip an unbiased coin ten times, the probability of getting an even number of heads is the same as the probability of getting an odd number of heads". The latter type of thing is really the meat and potatoes of probability!

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Even more interesting: if you flip a *biased* coin ten times, the $\binom{10}{5}$ outcomes where we get $5$ heads and $5$ tails are all equally likely. Uniformity appears out of non-uniformity!

Answer (score 1):

> For instance, how do you prove $P$(ℎ)=$P$()?

I don't think we can ever prove that mathematically, without resorting to circular reasoning at some level. But do we need a proof?

In problems involving probability, "fairness" is assumed unless there's a reason not to. And for a *fair* coin (dice or something similar), outcomes are equiprobable, by definition. The next question might be - **is it reasonable to assume that for a fair coin *heads* or *tails* are equally likely outcomes?**

I, like probably everyone else, would say yes. We can imagine a perfect coin in which the two faces are perfectly symmetrical (I mean, there will have to be something to make one face recognizabe as different from the other but let's pretend that's negligible). And if the faces are truly symmetrical, then there's no logical reason why one outcome should win over the other. In fact, symmetry of faces must imply symmetry of outcome, making the two outcomes equally likely.

**Also, is such an assumption necessary?**

While it may not be necessary, it makes things simpler and easier, especially when introducing the concept of probability to a learner. Just by using one word, *fair*, we are able to communicate that the probability of getting a heads (or tails) is $1/2$ - something in line with what we would expect intuitively.

A more accurate treatment, on the other hand, might look something like this (as suggested by *Misha Lavrov* in the comments) -

> ...an assumption that $Pr[\text{heads}]=p$ and $Pr[\text{tails}]=1−p$,
> writing down expressions like ${n \choose k}p^k(1−p)^{n-k}$ that don't
> require a uniform probability space.

Comment: The first two sentences in the second paragraph here provide the the answer. A fair coin is fair by definition of "fair". The rest of the answer digresses into an analysis of real coins,

Comment: -1: Fairness is an assumption, not a necessity. What mathematical models are useful to describe reality is a problem of scientific modeling, which cannot be treated purely mathematically. Also, typically there is dynamical bias in coins (they tend to come up a bit more often on the side that they were tossed from), see [Diaconis-Holmes-Montgomery](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20453950).

Comment: Hmm, I was trying to explain why having such a definition is both reasonable and necessary. That said, I can surely benefit from learning how to be concise and precise. Would you say the answer would be better off with those two sentences only?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I'll be happy to learn. But one, I said in most cases that assumption is necessary, not always. Perhaps I should have added "in the context of teaching/learning probability". And two, absent such an assumption, don't you think much of the text that introduces people to probability would need to be rewritten? And perhaps we would never have had that assumption to begin with if there wasn't necessary (again, not in the strictly literal sense)?

Comment: I, for one, appreciate the commentary that Haris provided as it has helped me to understand more about the fair coin.

Comment: I should add that my understanding of probability is very elementary, perhaps that's obvious.

Comment: @Cynicrom thank you! I am glad you found it helpful.

Comment: I'm unconvinced by the last paragraph. We can get equally far with an assumption that $\Pr[\text{heads}] = p$ and $\Pr[\text{tails}] = 1-p$, writing down expressions like $\binom nk p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$ that don't require a uniform probability space.

Comment: @Haris I agree with Misha, you can also work for example with biased coins :) But I think what you mean is that "it is necessary to make an assumption on the distribution of the coin in order to make concrete calculations with it (for example in a probability course)". I fully agree with that statement!

Comment: @MishaLavrov MaximilianJanisch Thinking about it, I realized it would be best to modify that part of the answer. Appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

In full generality, we can never argue with 100% certainty that any physical experiment is correctly modeled by any probabilistic model - whether it has uniform probabilities or not. We can conclude that a model is pretty close to the truth by doing repeated experiments, but we are also guided by wanting a useful model.

Here are some reasons to use uniform models in probability:

**Simplicity.** Sometimes the calculations would just become terrible if we did not assume equally-likely outcomes, so if that assumption is not too wrong, we can use it to simplify our life.

**Symmetry.** If there are $n$ possible outcomes, and no reason to favor any outcome over the others, we may start by assuming that each one has probability $\frac1n$, because it's a very simple model and we don't have a reason to want a more complicated one yet. How long we stick with this depends on how much we know about the experiment, which brings us to...

**A starting point for inference.** More sophisticated techniques try to use probabilistic techniques to figure out *how* to model the random experiment. For example:

- A Bayesian statistician might assume a uniform prior distribution (treating everything as equally likely to start width) and update according to the evidence.
- A frequentist statistician might treat the uniform distribution as a null hypothesis to see if there's evidence that the real distribution could be biased in any significant way.

**Aspirational uniformity.** In the case of coins and dice, we are using the physical objects because we *want* something that behaves uniformly. We can treat a statement like "the probability of rolling doubles on a pair of fair dice is $\frac16$" as something we aspire to. The *ideal* fair pair of dice would achieve this probability exactly, *real* dice probably aren't quite there, but as our manufacturing techniques improve, we can get closer to this ideal.

**Emergent uniformity.** Sometimes, uniformity appears in a non-uniform probability space. Here is an example.

Suppose you have a coin (not necessarily fair) and want to pick between three random outcomes uniformly. You can do this as follows. First, flip the coin three times. If all three results are the same, start over, until they are not. Now, output result $1$, $2$, and $3$ according to whether it's the first, second, or third flip that's "the odd one out".

Here, results $1$, $2$, and $3$ are equally likely under much weaker assumptions: simply that our coin flips are *independent* (one coin flip doesn't affect another) and *identically distributed* (the coin doesn't change its probability of landing on "heads" over time). Actually, all of the reasons above also double as reasons why we might make these weaker assumptions, even if we're not 100% true they are valid!